# Montar array com permissions de usuários

Tags: php, array, laravel

Preciso montar um array em PHP (LARAVEL) e não estou conseguindo achar uma maneira de fazer.

Tenho um sistema de users com roles  e permissions. Quando visualizo o user, eu listo todas as permissions, mas uma em baixo da outra.
Ex:

```
>     users-index
>     users-show
>     users-create
>     roles-create
>     roles-delete
```

Mas gostaria de fazer o seguinte:

Pegar todas essas permissions e separa-las por categoria pra listar em tabelaa separadas, onde esta é a caregoria é a palavra antes do "-" (USERS-index), ex de array:

> ArrayAll = [
>                users = [
>                               users-index,
>                               users-show,
>                               users-create
>                              ]
>                 roles = [
>                               roles-create,
>                               roles-delete
>                             ]
>                             ]

Conto com ideias!
Abraços

Comment: Parece que isso vai nos levar a uma resposta gigante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi bem acho que isso te ajuda

```
$teuArrayDePermissoes = array('users-index','users-show','users-create','roles-create','roles-delete');
$newArray = array();
foreach($teuArrayDePermissoes as $permissao){
    $parts = explode("-", $permissao);
    $newArray[$parts[0]][] = $permissao;
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Deve exibir na saída o array que tu queres

Comment: Show de bola, era isso mesmo. Só nao entendi a parte do: $newArray[$parts[0] [ ] ] = .... Sei que no $novoArray... Terá a key como $parts e o value como permissão... Mas o por que dos conchetes vazios apos a key?

Comment: $parts[0] vai ter a primeira chave, por exemplo 'user' ou 'roles', então essa linha que tu não entendeu vai preencher o array como uma matriz ou um array de arrays, depois tu vai acessar $newArray['users'] e ele vai retornar um array com [ users-index, users-show, users-create ]... em php tu pode dizer $array[] = ... como um atalho para $array[x] = ... onde x seria o próximo indice, assim tu insere sem uma chave e no final do array